# How I can resolve this deployment error? I am using NeatBeans7.4 and tomcat server my project is maven spring

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

```
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext4416725786674926512.xml&path=/kipaniaSiteMarchand
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /kipaniaSiteMarchand but context failed to start
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.

at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:238)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:235)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: You might want to consider a few things if you expect answers rather than downvotes: 1) read [ask], 2) provide more details, e.g. what you've tried to do etc. 3) since the log states "See the server log for details." you might want to have a look there and provide the relevant details

Comment: thank you for the response Thomas. I saw the log file of the  server it seems correct.when i run the application than  its show the deployment error.